# Batch Process Copy rename and move file to move copy file location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with 5,000 images

I need to be asked file name wanted and copy from one folder rename file and move copy to a new folder .

I have used a batch process but it is only copying files from a .txt file

I would like to change filelist to a pop up window asking which file name I want and to set the rename as

Original file name 
    Image1.jpg 
    Image2.jpg

Rename file 
    Image1_1234.jpg 
    Image2_1234.jpg
The _1234 will always stay the same 
Any help would be much appreciated

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\Users\sid\Desktop\Artworks
set Target=C:\Users\sid\Desktop\Artworks Copy
set FileList=C:\Users\siddique.gaffar\Desktop\Artwork TXT File\Book1.txt
echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do copy "%Source%\%%a"         
"%Target%"


:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: `copy "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"` should be in a single line -- is this just a typo here, or do you have the line-break in your script too? And this question is not related to [tag:php], right?

Comment: Line-break is in the script,  sorry not related to php, open to any options

Comment: There must not be a line-break in that line. Anyway, please provide more detail about what you want to be prompted and how to rename files. It would be quite helpful to help if you provided your own attempts of implementing the desired changes...

Comment: I coding skills are very basic                                                                            
I want to be prompted to input file name that I am looking for (image01) I want to rename the file (image01_1234)

Comment: Sorry wanted to make sure you got my last message